# Multiple Images and Text not correctly placing or not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get some practise done for HTML/CSS/JavaScript, I am very new to the languages hence why I'm absolutely clueless of why this is happening.

I'm trying to get the text to position in between the top 2 images, however, now it is not even showing, also, the movement and positioning of the pictures seems really weird, its like they are interconnected to something or something is stopping them.

HTML File:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="positioning.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Japanese Journey!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="JapanPic.jpg" width="400" height="250" alt="Japan Background" class="topleft">
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 70px; margin-top: -175px;">Learning Japanese</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="JapanPic.jpg" width="400" height="250" alt="Japan Background" class="topright">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="JapaneseN4.png" width="400" height="500" alt="Japanese N4 Certificate" class="bottomright">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.image{
    position: relative;
}

.topright {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 5px solid #555;
}

.topleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 5px solid #555;
}

.bottomright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 5px solid #555;

}
```

And Another CSS file:

```
.header {
    padding: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #c3b091;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

toptext {
    font-size: 70px;
    height: 600;
    width: 900;
}
```

Comment: while using `position: absolute` works fine in many cases, in most cases such as yours it might not be the most manageable option to use. I would recommend that you look at other kinds of positioning such as flexbox and grid

Answer (score 0):

Consider using flexbox for improved layout control, simplifying alignment and maintenance of design elements. Here's a quick rundown of flexbox basics for reference.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Flexbox Tutorial</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            height: 544px; 
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid black;
            display: flex; /* Initialize the container as a flex box */
            
            /* Flex properties for a flex container */

            /* flex-direction: row; (Default value of flex-direction is row) */
            /* flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: column-reverse; */
            

            /* flex-wrap: wrap; (Default value of flex-direction is no-wrap) */
            /* flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; */

            /* This is a shorthand for flex-direction: and flex-wrap: ;; */
            /* flex-flow: row-reverse wrap; */ 

            /* justify-content will justify the content in horizontal direction */
            /* justify-content: center; */
            /* justify-content: space-between; */
            /* justify-content: space-evenly; */
            /* justify-content: space-around; */

            /* justify-content will justify the content in vertical direction */
            /* align-items: center; */
            /* align-items: flex-end; */
            /* align-items: flex-start; */
            /* align-items: stretch; */ 
        }
        .item{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: tomato;
            border: 2px solid green;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 3px;
        }

        #item-1{
            /* Flex properties for a flex item */
            /* Higher the order, later it shows up in the container */
            /* order: 2; */

            /* flex-grow: 2;
            flex-shrink: 2; */

        }
        #item-2{
            /* flex-grow: 3;
            flex-shrink: 3 ; */
            flex-basis: 160px;
            /* when flex-direction is set to row flex-basis: will control width */
            /* when flex-direction is set to column flex-basis: will control height */
        }
        #item-3{
            /* flex: 2 2 230px; */
            align-self: flex-start;
            align-self: flex-end;
            align-self: center;

            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is Flexbox Tutorial</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item" id="item-1">First Box</div>
        <div class="item" id="item-2">Second Box</div>
        <div class="item" id="item-3">Third Box</div>
        <!-- <div class="item" id="item-4">Fourth Box</div>
        <div class="item" id="item-5">Fifth Box</div>
        <div class="item" id="item-6">Sixth Box</div> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```